# Getting started with yiiexcel extension

Tags: excel, yii

I have a hurdle, seem can't get to internalize how to setup yii excel onto my web application.

I tried to follow the guidelines, however, there is something I can't understand as stated from this guide. To which index.php was it referring to?

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiiexcel/

```
Edit index.php file and register the YiiExcel autoloader:
```

Is there anyone here who was successful to install and use the yii excel extension for yii, can you please lend me a hand.

Been working on this for days now, and seem to end nowhere as it is apparent that I don't know what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

that is the entry point of your application

**root**

-- index.php `<-- this file`

------protected

------images